# Edit cursing out of a question

Tags: discussion, editing, etiquette

I recently edited [this question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/posts/27893/revisions), taking what I assume is a universally accepted form of "cursing" out of the question and converting it to a version more commonly accepted in civilized discourse.

My questions are:

- **What is SE policy (policies) on cleaning up bad (cursing) language?**
- **If there's not a universal SE policy, what is our policy or what should our policy be?**

Comment: Thanks for that edit, and this question! I removed something similar, though not quite as bad, on another SE site, and was chastised and made fun of. Thank you for keeping your site clean for everyone! :)

Comment: @Sue - No worries. Thank you for being here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In terms of formal policy, you have (["be nice"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)) on the official behaviour page. There's also [this meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-cursing-swear-words-or-vulgar-language-allowed-on-se-sites) saying cursing is not allowed, punishable with a warning, or timed suspension for frequent offenders, and [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29931/what-is-the-rationale-behind-the-no-cursing-rule) discussing it. There's also a [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites), which links to the first meta answer...

I'd agree that we should be keeping to language that is accepted in civilised discourse - many people read SE sites at work, or amongst family, so the language should be suitable for such environments - also, expletives don't look very professional...